# Error interpreting categorical data: all items must be hashable [statsmodel]

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, hashable

I'm trying to use linear mixed-effects model from statsmodel. And I get an error message:

```
Error interpreting categorical data: all items must be hashable
    fc ~ group * session
    ^^
```

Where "fc" is a column in my data frame which contains a 1D array (1x2346).
Data frame looks like:

```
      subj group session                                                 fc
0      0     1       1  [0.2922897321426426, 0.8889104138397078, 0.716...
1      0     1       2  [0.2900923963035335, 0.8475482137619675, 0.713...
2      1     1       1  [0.5929015237174594, 0.24248656443213046, 0.26...
3      1     1       2  [0.20802496215095026, 0.9411248464107547, 0.93...
```

Code:

```
my_model_fit = smf.mixedlm("fc ~ group * session", df, groups=df["subj"]).fit()
my_model_fit.random_effects
my_model_fit.summary()
```

I would appreciate any help :)

[error message and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxWQh.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to fit vectors (`fc`) based on group and session values. I'm not sure if `statsmodels` can do that, but you may find it easier to break `fc` into separate columns and fit each of those individually. That will give the same effect as fitting the whole `fc` vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know, that lists are not hashable, because they are mutable. You could use tuples instead of lists, then it should work. But I doubt, that it is a good idea to use category as the datatype anyways, because most likely your vectors will not repeat (you will hardly have exactly the same vector in two rows) and so category doesn't make much sense here.

So in short, check if your "arrays" really repeat, so that several rows use equal array values. If that isn't the case, rather use a regular object column instead of category. Then it also doesn't matter much if you store them as lists or tuples. But if they repeat several times, you can use category to safe space, but then you should use tuples instead.

Check:

```
hash(list([1,2,3]))
hash(tuple([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  It looks like it helps with the initial error. But now I get a new one:
`endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (52, 52). This occurs when the variable converted to endog is non-numeric (e.g., bool or str). `

Comment: I don't know, what endog is, but maybe this article helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584416/python-endog-has-evaluated-to-an-array-with-multiple-columns